Grub2 does not load grub.cfg in $fw_path automatically (ubuntu 24.04)
Ubuntu 24.04
Grub Version: 2.12
Setup - customized image with grub as bootloader that loads an iso file. The same steps were previously working fine when using ubuntu 22.04. The issue happens only on 24.04.
How is grub setup?
sudo qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 <new disk image file that was created>
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p3 /tmp/boot/
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 /tmp/efi/
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/tmp/efi/ --boot-directory=/tmp/boot/ --modules="ext2 fat part_gpt xzio squash4" --removable --compress=xz

Write menuentries to /tmp/boot/grub/grub.cfg
   set default="0"
    set timeout=2
    
    menuentry "ISO1" {
      ISO=/custom.iso
      insmod all_video
    
      set root='(hd0,1)'
      search --no-floppy --label ISO --set=root
      loopback loop $ISO
      linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$ISO textonly quiet splash console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200
      initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.img
    }

What Happens on boot ?
System boots into grub prompt. Grub does not load /EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg automatically
Workaround:
In Grub prompt enter this command:
source $fw_path/grub.cfg

Note: Value of fw_path='(hd0,gpt2/EFI/BOOT)' in grub prompt (default value)
Contents of /EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg:
search.fs_uuid 4d4b6cd0-53bb-4bd3-90fb-f825d2902f70 root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

Any ideas on whether something changed on grub2 or if I need any additional steps to get this working with grub 2.12 in ubuntu24.04  ?
